# Chipmunk: How to set cpBody position in world space after adding a joint

Tags: objective-c, chipmunk, physics-engine

I am superimposing bodies in a space by drag and drop. Once two sprites collide I set a pin joint (I tried also with pivot joint 2). After setting the joint when I set the body position, some times it works fine and some times the behavior is weird. My question is How to set the body position after setting a joint? And, Could the joint set the body position automatically? THanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes. but set the position of a body after it has had a joint connected is not a good method . you can use the method something like mouse-joint to move the position of body. the joint will work automatically .